# Is there a way to skip the opening logos in Deus Ex: Human Revolution?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I'm really enjoying the newest Deus Ex, but I'm not enjoying sitting through the logos of the assorted developers and publishers each time the game loads. I remember modifying a file (maybe a .ini) in Borderlands to skip its opening logos so it wasn't so tedious, but I can't remember how this was done, or if the same thing is possible in DE:HR.

Anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you playing on steam? If you are, you can try the "-nointro" command line argument.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer, since every copy requires steam, your comment should be the answer

Comment: nvm, I just tried putting -nointro in my launch options and it didn't work

Comment: @yx_ I didn't realize it was a steamworks game.

Comment: Your decision, of course, but you might want to change the accepted answer. Replacing files with ones from previous versions is probably not a very good idea, especially considering the alternative.

Comment: Probably a good idea...which reminds me, I could probably change that file back now...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The September 15th, 2011 update adds the ability to skip through the opening logos using the **space bar** ([source](http://store.steampowered.com/news/6272/)):

> • Intro logos can now be skipped on all but the first run of the game.

Answer (score 7):

There is currently no known command-line argument or .ini setting to disable the intro movies. To make it even worse, the intro files are stored together in "bigfiles" ([confirmed by a forum administrator](http://forums.eidosgames.com/showpost.php?p=1656018&postcount=5)). So you can't replace them with zero-length movies as if the movies were individual files.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you can replace your patch0.000 with **[this one](http://www.mediafire.com/?9w9qr7um9zzodtu)** to skip the intro with ENTER.

Answer (score 5):

I've followed the logic through with Ollydbg and it seems that originally they used to have a menu option for toggling intro movies on/off in the Options menu but they took it out. Instead they are hardcoding the instruction to toggle it on by default. And, I believe the reason there is no INI file/command-line/dev console option for toggling it is that they didn't provide one. The "UI/Disable Intro" string is just the title of the option for display in the Options menu and the longer string is the description. You'll notice that it is the only command in the entire strings table that lacks a command associated with it. They might add this in a future update if enough customers are angry about it, however. Perhaps we should petition them to do this.

On an unrelated note, someone out there might find these useful. I found them while looking for a way to solve the intro problem.

intro
dynamic_ads
g_unlockedDLCPacks
infinite_ammo
immortal
accesscode
nohud
uberobject_info
g_aimAssist

Answer (score 4):

There **is** a way to disable this intro. A parameter or command line disables it: **[Assembly proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01Gdr.jpg)** (check the highlighted part). We just don't know the command yet, and because I got no skill at assembly, I can't trace the command.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I heard about this mod today that unlocks debug mode with an option to skip the menus...so that's something...

http://forums.eidosgames.com/showthread.php?t=121245